# Elementwise multiplication of characters in a list by numbers from a given shorter range while ignoring spaces and digits and joining result together

Tags: python, string, list

I want to multiply every letter of a word based on the starting and ending range given. My current code is as follows, but it doesn't work as intended:

```
word = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'm', 'e']
start = 3
end = 5
for b in range(start, end + 1):
    for a in word:
        print(a * b, end='')
```

My output is:

```
hhheeelllpppmmmeeehhhheeeellllppppmmmmeeeehhhhheeeeelllllpppppmmmmmeeeee
```

But I want to receive:

```
hhheeeelllllpppmmmmeeeee
```

The flow of this program should be like this:

```
helpme
345345
```

In addition, how could I ignore spaces and digits in the list? For example, my input would be:

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'p', ' ', 'm', 'e']
start = 3
end = 5
```

And my output:

```
hhheeeelllllppp mmmmeeeee
```

so the multiplications should be:

```
help me
3453145
```

Comment: the issue here is that for every integer in your `range` object you are performing the multiplication, hence you are seeing a repeated string with increasing frequency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like the following, using `zip` and [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
import itertools

word = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'm', 'e']
start = 3
end = 5

for a, b in zip(itertools.cycle(range(start, end + 1)), word):
    print(b*a, end = '')
```

**Output:**

```
hhheeeelllllpppmmmmeeeee
```

Alternatively, you could do this using a modulo operator and `enumerate`:

```
word = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'm', 'e']
start = 3
end = 5

lst = list(range(start, end + 1))

for i, a in enumerate(word):
    print(a*lst[i%len(lst)], end='')
```

**To ignore certain characters:**

```
import itertools

word = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'p', ' ', '1', 'm', 'e']
start = 3
end = 5

characters_to_ignore=' 0123456789'

gen = itertools.cycle(range(start, end + 1))

lst = [(x, next(gen)) if x not in characters_to_ignore else (x, 1) for x in word]

for a, b in lst:
    print(a*b, end='')
```

Output:

```
hhheeeelllllppp 1mmmmeeeee
```

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehension and join:

```
word = "helpme"
start = 3
end = 5

r = list(range(start, end + 1))

print(''.join([l * r[i % len(r)] for i, l in enumerate(word)]))
```

### Output

```
hhheeeelllllpppmmmmeeeee
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the spaces in, just not multiply them, or not have them at all? Updated answer for the first case.

Comment: yes, i want to keep spaces and not multiplying them.

Answer (score 3):

Already good answers have been given. Just want to add mine which is one liner (just for a change). You should ideally use a well readable and separated code but as I said, this solution is to just bring out 'pythonic variety' that exists :-).

```py
word = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'm', 'e']
print("".join(list(map(lambda a: a[0]*a[1], zip(word,list(range(3,6))*(len(word)//3))))))
```

Output is as below

```py
hhheeeelllllpppmmmmeeeee
```

**Lines added later**

**Edited after seeing a request of word list with space embedded in it**

@Faded I can't think of a 'single line' solution without destroying sanity checks beyond repair. Everything has limits and I have hit the limit for producing 'one line' solution for the problem you have described. It could only be me and somebody might have very easy solution using single line python expression. We should wait for that special torch-bearer.

In the meanwhile, it is very easy to achieve the same with a multiline program. One out of many possible solution is as below.

```py
word = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'p', '','m', 'e']
FinalList = []
MultiplierCount = 3
for i in word:
    if len(i) != 0:
        FinalList.append(i*MultiplierCount)
        MultiplierCount += 1
        if MultiplierCount > 5:
            MultiplierCount = 3
    else:
        FinalList.append(' ')

FinalOutput = "".join(FinalList)
print(FinalOutput)
```

It produces the following output.

```py
hhheeeelllllppp mmmmeeeee
```

Comment: I am sorry, I could not underrstand. By spaces you mean ..?

Comment: example if the word given is ['h', 'e', 'l', 'p', ' ', 'm', 'e'] output should be like this hhheeeelllllppp mmmmeeeee

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `enumerate` and modulus operators here:

```py
word = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'm', 'e']
start = 3
end = 5
for i,a in enumerate(word):
    print(a * (i%(end-start+1)+start), end='')
```

What's happening in your original code is that you're iterating through the whole word 3 times, once for each number in the range 3-6 exclusive. In this code, we use the index of the character mod 3 (end-start+1), and then add 3. So for any given number, it will give us a result of 3, 4, or 5.

**EDIT:**

I can't think of any logical way for you to use a nested for-loop to solve this without getting really complicated for no reason. You'll either end up iterating over range(3,6) for each letter of your word, or, like you're already doing, iterating through each letter of your word once for each number in range(3,6).

Comment: thanks sir. but how about if it will ignore spaces?

Comment: Use `filter` on your list before you iterate through it. `word = filter(lambda x: x != " ", word)`. If you need more assistance, I would recommend opening a new question.